# ActiveX cannot create Object: Object required 424 error

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, crystal-reports

In classic ASP, I am trying to create an ActiveX object. Basically, I am trying to create a Crystsal Reports Runtime object.
Dim oCR = CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application")

I am getting "ActiveX cannot create object" error.
This works fine on another developer machine. And both developer machines have Windows 7 VB 6 EE with SP 6 and Crystal Reports Developer edition 13.0.

Help needed :-(

Comment: Do you mean to create the ActiveX object on the client? If not, you need to use `Server.CreateObject(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If this is classic ASP, with VBScript, then:

```
Dim oCR = CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application")
```

... is definitely not going to work. This should be:

```
Dim oCR 
Set oCR = CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application")
```

As for the "ActiveX cannot create object" error, this is due to an installation failure of the Crystal Reports component. I would recommend you first try reinstalling the component. Failing that, look in the installation folder, and work out which file implements the ActiveX component (crtslv.dll ?). Then go to a command line and type:

```
regsvr32.exe "<component DLL file>"
```